# How to print Strings from a file with specific way in java?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I have this file with name "examples.txt" with data
a1 b4
a7 b6
a3 b9
and I want to print from every line every string separately for example
a1 b4
Ι wrote this code

```
try  
{   
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("example.txt");  
}  
catch (FileNotFoundException e)  
{    
    System.out.println("Problem opening file.");   
    System.exit(0);    
}  
Scanner inputReader = new Scanner(inputStream);  
while (inputReader.hasNextLine())  
{                           
    System.out.println(inputReader.next());  
    System.out.println(inputReader.next());  
}
```

This code does exactly what I want, print all data until last line, but it causes a run-time error java.util.NoSuchElementException and I don't understand why. Is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Please format your question and remove all the "enter code here"

Comment: What do you think is the purpose of `hasNextLine`?

Comment: Have you tried running a debugger and stepping through?  On what line does the exception occur? Did you inspect what the inputReader has at the time?

Comment: -The purpose of hasNextLine is to return a boolean value if file has any more lines to read. @SotiriosDelimanolis                                                                                                             - No, I didn't because I get all the strings from file normally. So I think the exception occurs because when program reaches to last line with values, tries to get nextLine maybe because finds nextLine char '/n' and has no values to get. If I use hasNext() I don't have any problem. Brandon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is this:

```
// Iterate as long as you have remaining lines
while (inputReader.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = inputReader.nextLine();
    // For each line, slip the tokens using space as separator
    for (String token : line.split(" ")) {
        System.out.println(token);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a1
b4
a7
b6
a3
b9
```

**Response update:**

Actually your code also works, the problem that you face is probably due to an empty line at the end of your file, indeed as it is a true line even if it is empty `hasNextLine()` will return `true` but since there is no more token left it throws `NoSuchElementException` when you call `next()`. With my approach you don't have this problem because an empty line will return an empty array.

Comment: thank you. I thought of using a way with split and I will use it but I can't understand the previous error yet.